# Gradle running bat file as dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, gradle

We have a .bat file we use to generate some source code.  It's smart enough to put all the generated .java files in the right places in the project.

I've defined a gradle task like this:

```
task createPojos(type:Exec) {
    workingDir "$dirXsd"
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'createPojos.bat'
}
```

I've also defined this task in build.gradle as the defaultTask. This works, and when I run 'gradle' from the command line, or execute the createPojo task from Eclipse, it generates the code as expected.  But I'd like to define it as a dependency instead so that when I do a Gradle-->Refresh All from Eclipse it runs the task above that runs the .bat.

I've tried to figure out how to run my createPojo task as a dependency, but have failed.  I must not understand Gradle concepts very well--can you specify one of your custom tasks as a dependency?  Not a dependency to another task, but something that goes in the dependency section of the build.gradle file?  Everything I try gives me some kind of gradle error when I do a refresh all.  Here's one attempt for example:

```
dependencies {
    createPojos() // how do I invoke createPojos from here?
}
A problem occurred evaluating project ':WebTransport'.
> Could not find method createPojos() for arguments [] on project ':WebTransport'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general You can run a task by calling `execute` method the instance of particular task. But this is *definitely* **not** how the task should be invoked.

If You need to call `createPojos()` in `dependencies` block move its logic to a method defined in `build.gradle` file and call the method directly in `dependencies` and in task action.

You know that `createPojos()` will be called in `dependencies` every time gradle is invoked? I don't know what exactly is invoked when *Refresh all* is run unfortunately but I suppose You won't alter it's behavior with this nasty task invocation.

If You need to put the generated classes under src folder create a task that generates the files and puts it under the desired location. I assume that if the classed are generated, they won't be edited. If so create other project that generates the classes, compiles them and ship as a jar file. Then in the current project just add a dependency for the jar being generated.

And finally, You can't specify a task as a dependency, at least not it the way You think of it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I did finally manage to get it to do what I wanted with this in the dependencies section:  tasks.createPojos.execute().  But I had to define my task above the dependencies.  I agree that we should separate it into another project and make a jar, because the code will not be changing after generation.

Answer (score 1):

You want a task dependency, not a module dependency (these are very different things). Something like `eclipse.dependsOn("createPojos")`. However, from what I remember, "Gradle->Refresh" in Eclipse only refreshes module dependencies but doesn't run any tasks. Therefore, you may have to reimport the project, which will run `eclipse` and any other task specified in the import dialog.